# Python DataFrame: How to replace Nan with value on one specific position

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace NA value at a specific position with another value using pd.DataFrame.fillna(previous_value, value, inplace = True). Although it's no error showing up in the running process, the original Na value hasn't been replaced yet.

```
Data[pd.isnull(Data["gender"])]
```

Data Output:

[image]

Replace Code:

```
 Data.loc[[2956]]["gender"].replace(np.nan, "F",inplace = True)
```

Data after replacement

```
Data.loc[[2956]]
```

Dataset after replacement:

[image]

Any idea how it happened?

Comment: might want to try Data.loc[[2956], ["gender"]]= Data.fillna("F")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dataframe.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) isn't meant to replace a value at a single position to begin with, but to replace *all the values* that correspond to something. So in your example, by using replace the best result you could have is having 'Scout Schultz' and 'Tk Tk' 's genders set to 'F'.

Since you know that the row 2956 has NaN in 'gender' column, you can do something like

```
data.loc[2956, 'gender'] = 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this.

```
df.loc[2956,'gender'] = 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value using column and row, you take the value, not that position in the dataframe. And you can't use replace() for a single value.

You can just change the value using:

```
 Data["gender"].loc[[2956]] = 'F'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Data.loc[[2956]]["gender"].replace(None, "F",inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> One method you can try is without using replace. When you know the
> index just assign the value you want  Code:

```
Data.gender[2956]='F'
```